# How to get text between space in a string?

Tags: java

I have some string example :

String1.  "Today is beautiful day"
String2.  "I love Hanoi much"
String3.  "I like playing football"

I want to get some text between spaces in this string. Example in string 1,  i want to have text1 = "Today",
text2 = "is", text3 = "beautiful" and text4 = "day". The same for string2 and string3.

My string always have 3 space.
Thanks.

Comment: Documentation is your friend. The [javadoc for the String class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) pretty much tells you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 String[] parts = "Today is beautiful day".split(" ");
```

Comment: I use Blackberry Eclipse Plugin to code(java). But seem no method .split define for String. I do not know why

Comment: What version of Java is that using? If there is no regular-expression split, you need to make your own using indexOf or maybe a StringTokenizer.

Comment: It use jdk 1.6 and jre 1.6. No class StringTokeinizer, have a methof indexOf but it return int, not string.

Comment: I found method split source code and add it in my program. Maybe My Complier not define it. I have to define this medthod. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use String.split() in order to get that.

```
String s = "Today is beautiful day";
String[] vals = s.split(" ");
// vals will be an array containig the four separated words...
// vals[0] == "Today"
// vals[1] == "is"
// vals[2] == "beautiful"
// vals[3] == "day"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] values = someString.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is called `split`:

```
String input = "I like playing football";
String[] splitText = input.split(" ");
```

This will return the array `"I", "like", "playing", "football"`.